# Dirac Delta vs Kronecker Delta for Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta, kronecker-delta

As I understand it, the Dirac Delta function is commonly associated with the Fourier Transform because it produces exponential functions that can represent signals.
However, as the Dirac Delta function has infinite amplitude, it cannot really be used in the real world applications. As such, Kronecker Delta is commonly used as it has amplitude of 1. Similarly, the Discrete Fourier Transform is used instead of the Fourier Transform.

Is there any way that the Mathematical relation between the Dirac Delta and the Fourier Transform can be applied to the Kronecker Delta and the Discrete Fourier Transform?

Comment: What is the link between the Dirac delta and exponential functions?